# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Project' not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\chatend\app\Http\Controllers\ReqController.php on line 18

Tags: laravel

before this I have justified an error and this error appears afterwards, I have searched the sources but the results remain the same and I've seen the same problem in stackoverflow but still haven't gotten another correct response, please help

Comment: Can you post the code that caused the error?

Comment: $project        = Project::where('id', $id)->first();
        $user           = User::where('id', $project->userid)->first();
        $service        = Services::where('id', $id)->first();
        $labelrelations = Labelrelations::where('id', $id)->first();

Comment: from this code it says that the project class, user, service, and labelrelations do not exist, is the problem in the model?

Comment: I think you forgot to use the class on the top of the file, like `use App\Model\Project;`

Answer (score 1):

This clearly indicates you have a `Model` or similar you have not included.

You will probably have a class similar to this.

```
public class ReqController {

     public function show($id)
     {
         return Project::find($id);
     }
}
```

To make this work in your case, you need to include the Project model in the top of the file, i assumed the path is used as in the standard `Laravel` folder structure.

```
use App\Models\Project;
```